# How to fetch class instead of array in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I am able to fetch my data from database by using this structure:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Emails')
->find(8081);
```

When I do that, I am able to get my data like this:

```
$user->getColumnNameHere();
```

Basically, I am able to use **Entity** Class.

But if I want to use QueryBuilder instead of `find` I am only getting associative arrays.

```
$product->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->where('p.idx = :idx')
        ->select('p.columnNameHere')
        ->setParameter('idx', 8081)
        ->orderBy('p.idx', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery();
        $product = $query->getResult();
```

$product returns as array. Is it possible to fetch it with Entity Manager Class? If yes, how?

I digg the documentation but it seems not possible or not exist in the doc or I'm just blind :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes you can, usually using:

```
$repository
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute()
;
```

This should return you an array of entities.

If you want to get a single entity result, use either `getSingleResult` or `getOneOrNullResult`:

```
$repository
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getOneOrNullResult()
;
```

Warning: These method can potentially throw `NonUniqueResultException`.

**Edit:** Ok, so the question was about partial objects: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html

Answer (score 18):

you can get an object instead of array by using "Partial Objects".

here is a tested example with DoctrineORM 2.2.2:

```
// create query builder
// $em is the EntityManager
$qb    = $em->createQueryBuilder();

// specify the fields to fetch (unselected fields will have a null value)
$qb->select  ('partial p.{id,pubDate,title,summary}')
   ->from    ('Project\Entity\Post', 'p')
   ->where   ('p.isActive = 1')
   ->orderBy ('p.pubDate', 'desc');

$q      = $qb->getQuery();

$result = $q->getResult();
var_dump($result); // => object
```

Comment: @user1191081 can give code example of using **Joins** where this doesn't work, thanks.

Comment: What I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you wish to return an object from your original query:

```
    $product->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->setMaxResults(1)
    ->where('p.idx = :idx')
    ->select('p.columnNameHere')
    ->setParameter('idx', 8081)
    ->orderBy('p.idx', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery();
    $product = $query->getResult();
```

**Remove this line**

```
->select('p.columnNameHere')
```

As soon as you use select, it will return an array...

Comment: The question-related code itself was about loading as less data as possible so I suppose it's not an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4):

`getResult()` method returns a collection (an array) of entities. Use `getSingleResult()` if you're going to fetch only one object.

#### EDIT:

Oh, I just noticed that you want to fetch a single field of a single object. Use `getSingleScalarResult()` as @Florian suggests.

Comment: No, i will fetch few columns not one. The query in this question is just an example. Not all rows and not one row.

Comment: I think you mix the idea of column, row and entity. What @Crozin says is right.

Comment: Moreover, If you want to fetch only one column, then use `getSingleScalarResult`.

Comment: @Florian, Yes and no. The aquery in this question is just an example. Lets say i want to fetch 4 column. But i dont want to fetch with arrays i want to fetch with Entity Class? Like `$result->getColumn();` instead of `$result['column'];` I am missing something here so lighting me. :)

Comment: Ha, ok :) I think you cannot hydrate an entity if you dan't have all the columns in the resultset.

Comment: Using `QueryBuilder`, it should always fetch all columns for a given entity.

Comment: If you really want to partially hydrate your entity, use http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/partial-objects.html