# getResult() returns an object

Tags: symfony

I have a doctrine query who returns the following result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Club 2"
    ["points"]=>
    int(19)
    ["played"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Club 3"
    ["points"]=>
    int(6)
    ["played"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Is it possible that $query->getResult() returns an object instead of an array ?

And do something like this:

```
foreach ( $clubs AS $oneClub ) {

    echo $oneClub->name;

}
```

Entity code:

```
public function getUserClubs ( $pUserId ) {

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery(

        '
       SELECT club.id, club.name, user_club.points, user_club.played
       FROM TennisBundle:UsersClubs user_club
         INNER JOIN TennisBundle:Clubs club WITH club.id = user_club.club
       WHERE user_club.user = :user
       ORDER BY user_club.points DESC
       '

    ) -> setParameters( array(

            'user' => $pUserId

    ));

    try {

            var_dump( $query->getResult() ); die;
            return (object) $query->getResult();

    } catch ( \Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e ) {


    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the query?

Comment: Can you post related code?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov edited

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch class instead of array in Doctrine 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482085/how-to-fetch-class-instead-of-array-in-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 0):

This method should be placed in your "TennisBundle:UsersClubs" repository class:

```
public function getUserClubs ( $pUserId ) {

    $query= $this->createQueryBuilder('uc')
        ->join('inst.club', 'c')
        ->where('uc.user = :user')
        ->orderBy('uc.points', 'desc')
        ->setParameter('user', $pUserId)
        ->getQuery();

    $results = $query->getResult();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
}

or you can use "createQuery":

public function getUserClubs($pUserId) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT uc FROM TennisBundle:UsersClubs uc
            JOIN TennisBundle:Clubs c
            WHERE uc.user = :user
            ORDER BY uc.points DESC'
        )->setParameter('user', $pUserId);

   $results = $query->getResult();
}
```

Parse object results and retrieve your club data. I hope this helps.

```
// $result is instance of "TennisBundle:UsersClubs"
foreach ( $results AS $result) {
    // $club is instance of "TennisBundle:Clubs"
    $club = $result->getClub();
    echo $club->getName();

}
```

Comment: Ok thx, but I would like to keep using createQuery() instead of createQueryBuilder()