# Doctrine2 FETCH_CLASS

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Inglês It is possible to return an instance of class in Doctrine2?

PDO is very simple

```
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'model\vo\envio_vo');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch class instead of array in Doctrine 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482085/how-to-fetch-class-instead-of-array-in-doctrine-2)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. This will give you ArrayCollection of User objects

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u');
$qb->from('Entity\User', 'u');
$qb->innerJoin('Entity\UserMeta', 'um', 'WITH', 'um.user = u.id');
$qb->where('u.id = :UserId')->setParameter(':UserId', $userId);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

if you want ArrayCollection of User columns, you can change code like

```
$qb->select('u.*');
```